# how to get data from dialog

Tags: android

I have dialog class like this

```
class Dialog_Open_DataPicker exten dialog {
Dialog_Open_DataPicker(Context c){}
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_date_picker);
    }
}
```

I call that dialog like this:

```
Dialog_Open_DataPicker d = new Dialog_Open_DataPicker(Offer.this);
            d.show();
```

I want to get the date from my dialog to my activity, how please? thanks in advance

Comment: create one class name ABC. in that class create variable like public static String xxx = ""; and in your dialog do this : ABC.xxx = "hello". in your activity you can use like : Log.e("xxx is--->",""+ABC.xxx);

Comment: my first Comment is your answer. Please put your full code then i ll correct your code.

Comment: i got u and it works, write an answer please so i could accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creates and shows dialog for showing date. It sets value in given textbox in you Activity class.

```
public static void showDate(Context context,final TextView view)
{
   final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
   dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
   dialog.setContentView(R.layout.date_dialog);
   dialog.setCancelable(true);
   dialog.show();

   dialog.findViewById(R.id.set_time).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            DatePicker datePicker=(DatePicker)dialog.findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
            int year = datePicker.getYear();
            int month = datePicker.getMonth()+1;
            int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();

            StaticDateVariables.DATE_FROM_DATE_DIALOG=new StringBuilder()
            .append(month).append("-").append(day).append("-")
            .append(year).toString();

            view.setText(StaticDateVariables.DATE_FROM_DATE_DIALOG);


            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```